# Scipy.stats allows import of `norm` but not `norm_gen`

Tags: scipy, importerror, python-3.9, scipy.stats

I want to import the "class factory" of the normal distribution in Scipy to tweak it but I get an import error when doing so:

```py
In [5]: from scipy.stats import norm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [6]: from scipy.stats import norm_gen                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-033da3de46bb> in <module>
----> 1 from scipy.stats import norm_gen

ImportError: cannot import name 'norm_gen' from 'scipy.stats' (/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py)
```

I cannot make sense of this ImportError. How can I work around it? Except for pasting the code from norm_gen locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing it from `scipy.stats.distrubutions`. This is however a bit of a hack and is not guaranteed to be forward-compatible . You might want to reconsider your code and your reasons to inherit from `_gen` classes : those are an implementation detail. Inheriting from `rv_continuous` is supported though.

Comment: Many thanks @ev-br your trick gets the job done. About the future proofing concern: I should not need to bump my scipy dependence for now. I will keep a note on this technical debt item somewhere =)